# Failed to set (borderWidth) user defined inspected property on (UIView): ....this class is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: swift, xcode

I get the following error:
Failed to set (borderWidth) user defined inspected property on (UIView): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderWidth.

I looked over all the responses in StackOverflow and the most common solution is to find an unused outlet (!). This solution was useful in many cases but no such outlet exists this time.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this can help as I spent a couple of hours on that. Typically you may have an abandoned outlet (marked by !). However, in my case, the problem was with a non-used "User Defined Runtime Attributes".

In the identity inspector, I had attributes that were associated with UIView but not connected to anything.

StackOverflow doesn't allow me to embed a picture yet but if you check the link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N631n.png), The picture shows the correct attributes (note the 'custom view') at the top. The unused attributes were associated with UIView and once I deleted them, it resolved the issue.